# Multiple Applications, single domain how many SSL endpoints required?

Tags: ssl, heroku, ssl-certificate

I'm due to handover a project to a client, however they've requested that all requests go over https.

I have purchased a wildcard SSL certificate, however the application in whole is launched under 2 different heroku applications. (app/auth)

Am I correct in thinking that I will need 2 SSL endpoints or can I use the same SSL endpoint for both applications?? if so how?

**update from comments**
For example:

```
app.domain.com
auth.domain.com
```

I assume that this works due to the Wildcard SSL - a standard SSL certificate would not work here for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since both applications share the same domain, you can use one SSL endpoint.

- Add the SSL endpoint to one app.
- Add cname's for each application domain that point to the Heroku SSL endpoint
- Add the domains for each app with `heroku domains:add DOMAIN`

Heroku will handle the routing to each application via the SSL endpoint.

Comment: Does this work if you've got the apps on different sub domains eg app1.domain.com and app2.domain.com?

Comment: i got assigned same ssl end point for two different apps, with one being the wildcard domain. wonder how this would work